# Images source from localhost to web hosting

Tags: php, html

I have developed a site which contains images that links to an image from the root directory:

```
<a href="#"><img src="/cvsp/img/gallery/thumbs/1.jpg" data-description="" />
```

... where the `cvsp` is the name of my folder, like, `localhost/cvsp`.

The image points to `htdocs/cvsp/webroot/img/gallery/thumbs/1.jpg`

This works fine on localhost, but the problem is that when I host the website, it won't display the images in the directory.

This is my first time hosting a website.

my directory in hosting

```
/
   /webroot
       /img
          /gallery
```

Comment: Did you also put the image file on the host in the same directory structure?

Comment: have you checked it by removing "cvsp/"

Comment: Use some function to generate path to images.

Comment: yes the image are still intact in the same directory... I have tried removing cvsp/...also I tried putting ../img still no show.

Comment: but my css that points to a certain image works

Comment: Ok after a lot of trial and error! damn..its just case sensitivity. I uploaded .JPG whereas in the code I used .jpg...sorry guys you are all right

Comment: Case sensitive... I knew exactly the same problem :). Close your subject.

Answer (score 0):

In your server, I think you have root folder with all your source like this :

```
RootFolder (maybe 'www') 
  -index.html
  -img
     -gallery
       -thumbs
         -1.jpg
```

If you have an image in index.html, you can use absolute or relative path

RootFolder is the `root` so `/`

**Absolute**

```
<a href="#"><img src="/img/gallery/thumbs/1.jpg" data-description="" />
                      ^ root folder
```

**Relative**

```
<a href="#"><img src="img/gallery/thumbs/1.jpg" data-description="" />
```

Can you add the tree diagram to know exactly the synthax?

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="#"><img src="./img/gallery/thumbs/1.jpg" data-description="" />`

you should use  this as this is relative path